# How to achieve overlay with out using layerDrawable in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, overlay

I have two imageviews and I need to display one on top of other.

I do not want to use layerDrawable. I need perform zoom operation on this imageviews equally.

How to achieve overlay with out using layerDrawable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to place items on top of each other. You also try using a `RelativeLayout` and aligning the top and bottom of one `ImageView` to the top and bottom of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and put the ImageViews on it.